# sklearn linear regression is doesn't appear to fit correctly

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm putting together a simple OLS example from sklearn, and I'm noticing strange results. Below is the results

```py
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

model = Pipeline([('linear', LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True))])

n = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 10, n)
eps = np.random.randn(n)
y = 0.5 * x + -2.5 + eps

model.fit(y.reshape(-1, 1), x.reshape(-1, 1))
yhat = model.predict(x.reshape(-1, 1))
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, yhat, 'r')
```

[image]

It seems strange that the OLS fit is so off. Just looking for someone else to reproduce this before posting this on the main sklearn issue tracker. My versions are below

```
sklearn=0.22.1
python=3.6.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is where you did wrong

```
model.fit(y.reshape(-1, 1), x.reshape(-1, 1))
```

change to:

```
model.fit(x.reshape(-1, 1), y.reshape(-1, 1))
```